# ng-model seemingly only binding one way on ion-radio button inside modal view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic/Angular app, I have a scope variable which I instantiate like this:

```
$scope.org = 0;
```

I then have a modal dialog which I instantiate like this:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/picker-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    }
)
```

And load like this:

```
$scope.modal.show();
```

Inside my modal dialog definition, I have some data bound to my scope-level variable:

```
Currently selected: {{org}}            
<ion-radio ng-model="org" ng-value="0" name="grp1">Option zero</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="org" ng-value="1" name="grp1">Option one</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="org" ng-value="2" name="grp1">Option two</ion-radio>
```

Back on my main form I show the current value too:

```
Currently selected: {{org}}
```

All works great on the modal form - the value from the main scope feeds through fine and the user gets to pick.

However...

My org value never changes on the main form. How can this be? Changing the value of org from the main form feeds through to the modal form fine (so it's not ended up with some sort of single-instance scope) but selecting things on my subform doesn't change the org value in the main form.

Comment: you should always have a dot in an ng-model binding. If you use the "controller as" syntax it will take care of this for you. e.g. `ng-model="ctrl.org"` http://learnwebtutorials.com/why-ng-model-value-should-contain-a-dot

Comment: This works! Is there a chance you could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should always have a dot in an ng-model binding. If you use the "controller as" syntax it will take care of this for you. e.g. ng-model="ctrl.org"

For mroe details see:
http://learnwebtutorials.com/why-ng-model-value-should-contain-a-dot

Answer (score 0):

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl doesn't doesent directly use the scope you provided in the options argument `scope: $scope`, but creates a child scope.

If you want to access the original scope you have to reference it as $parent in your dialog template:

```
<ion-radio ng-model="$parent.org" ng-value="0" name="grp1">Option zero</ion-radio> 
...
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure this is true - switching my data to have a dot in its name (as per rob's comment on my post) does seem to fix it, which makes me think this isn't quite right.